# What program language is file '/usr/bin/apt-get' coded in? C or C++?

Tags: language-support, encoding

What programming language is the file `/usr/bin/apt-get` coded in?    C or C++?

I open the file 'apt-get' with encoding 'hex':

```
7f45 4c46 0201 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000
0300 3e00 0100 0000 6038 0000 0000 0000
4000 0000 0000 0000 60a1 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 4000 3800 0900 4000 1d00 1c00
0600 0000 0500 0000 4000 0000 0000 0000
4000 0000 0000 0000 4000 0000 0000 0000
f801 0000 0000 0000 f801 0000 0000 0000
0800 0000 0000 0000 0300 0000 0400 0000
3802 0000 0000 0000 3802 0000 0000 0000
3802 0000 0000 0000 1c00 0000 0000 0000
1c00 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000
0100 0000 0500 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
f08f 0000 0000 0000 f08f 0000 0000 0000
0000 2000 0000 0000 0100 0000 0600 0000
5098 0000 0000 0000 5098 2000 0000 0000
5098 2000 0000 0000 c807 0000 0000 0000
e00a 0000 0000 0000 0000 2000 0000 0000
0200 0000 0600 0000 a89a 0000 0000 0000
a89a 2000 0000 0000 a89a 2000 0000 0000
1002 0000 0000 0000 1002 0000 0000 0000
0800 0000 0000 0000 0400 0000 0400 0000
5402 0000 0000 0000 5402 0000 0000 0000
5402 0000 0000 0000 4400 0000 0000 0000
4400 0000 0000 0000 0400 0000 0000 0000
50e5 7464 0400 0000 e486 0000 0000 0000
e486 0000 0000 0000 e486 0000 0000 0000
f400 0000 0000 0000 f400 0000 0000 0000
0400 0000 0000 0000 51e5 7464 0600 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 1000 0000 0000 0000
52e5 7464 0400 0000 5098 0000 0000 0000
5098 2000 0000 0000 5098 2000 0000 0000
```

Comment: https://github.com/Debian/apt   looks to be cpp

Comment: `apt source apt`

Answer (score 1):

If you fetch the apt source code using:

```
apt-get source apt
```

and examine the package one can see that the apt tools are mainly written in C++ (look in the directory apt-pkg and the files are .cc suffixed source files, e.g. C++ source).

Comment: thanks a lot,but i want to know why i can't see the C++ files in this question using sublime_text, numbers are displayed,not chars ,how can i  solve the problem ?